# In Django, how do I access template values in the views.py?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-templates, django-views

I'm fairly new to Django and I'm working on a page that takes in user information. If all of the information is correct, it will proceed to the next page. However, if the user does not provide all given info, it will to refresh the page. My problem is that there are quite a bit of fields the user has to fill out and if the person misses any fields, I don't want them to have to re-type everything out. So my workaround for it is that in the views.py I created a dictionary and it populates it with the input names in the template. However, when I go to run the code, it gives me an error saying that the values in my dictionary do not exist. I'm now thinking that my dictionary is not actually accessing any of the template values.

Here is my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "Checklist/base.html" %}
{% block main_content %}
{% load static %}
  <html>
    <body>

      <form action="{% url 'Checklist:signin_check' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <li>
          <label for="driver_first_name">Driver First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="driver_first_name" value="" id="driver_first_name">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="driver_last_name">Driver Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="driver_last_name" value="" id="driver_last_name">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="driver_wwid">Driver WWID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="driver_WWID" value="" id="driver_WWID" maxlength="8"
              onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="co_driver_first_name">CO-Driver First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="co_driver_first_name" value="" id="co_driver_first_name">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="co_driver_last_name">CO-Driver Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="co_driver_last_name" value="" id="co_driver_last_name">
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="co_driver_wwid">CO-Driver WWID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="co_driver_WWID" value="" id="co_driver_WWID" maxlength="8"
              onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57">
        </li>
      <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Continue">
      </li>
      </ul>
      </form>

    </body>
  </html>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the views.py:

```
def signin_check(request):
    driver_info_model = Driver()
    if request.method == "POST":
        driver_info_form = Driver_Form(request.POST)
        c = {'driver_first_name':driver_first_name, 'driver_last_name':driver_last_name,
            'driver_WWID':driver_WWID, 'co_driver_first_name':co_driver_first_name,
            'co_driver_last_name':co_driver_last_name, 'co_driver_WWID': co_driver_WWID,}
        if driver_info_form.is_valid():
            driver_info_form.save()
            return render(request, 'Checklist/checklist.html')
    template = loader.get_template('Checklist/signin.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(c, request))
```

any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should be using Django forms for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, when I go to run the code, it gives me an error saying that
>   the values in my dictionary do not exist. I'm now thinking that my
>   dictionary is not actually accessing any of the template values.

From your views.py alone I'm guessing the exception you're running into is that you're assigning dictionary values that aren't defined.  For example, in `'driver_first_name':driver_first_name`, Python is looking for a variable named `driver_first_name` but you haven't defined it.  The data you're looking for, as Justin alluded to, can be found in `requests.POST`.

One solution, while more verbose, illustrates what needs to be done:

```
def signin_check(request):
    driver_info_model = Driver()
    if request.method == "POST":
        driver_info_form = Driver_Form(request.POST)
        driver_first_name = request.POST.get('driver_first_name', '')
        driver_last_name = request.POST.get('driver_last_name', '')
        driver_WWID = request.POST.get('driver_WWID', '')
        co_driver_first_name = request.POST.get('co_driver_first_name', '')
        co_driver_last_name = request.POST.get('co_driver_last_name', '')
        co_driver_WWID = request.POST.get('co_driver_WWID', '')
        c = {'driver_first_name': driver_first_name,
             'driver_last_name': driver_last_name,
             'driver_WWID': driver_WWID,
             'co_driver_first_name': co_driver_first_name,
             'co_driver_last_name': co_driver_last_name,
             'co_driver_WWID': co_driver_WWID, }
        if driver_info_form.is_valid():
            driver_info_form.save()
            return render(request, 'Checklist/checklist.html')
    template = loader.get_template('Checklist/signin.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(c, request))
```

> My problem is that there are quite a bit of fields the user has to
>   fill out and if the person misses any fields, I don't want them to
>   have to re-type everything out.

To address your second concern you'll need to deal with your HTML template.  Your input fields have a value of `""`, so any value you pass through your context is not going to reach any of them.  Luckily you're on the right path and you're quite close, so all you need to do is fill those values in.  For example:

```
<li>
    <label for="driver_first_name">Driver First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="driver_first_name" value="{{ driver_first_name }}" id="driver_first_name">
</li>
```

Note that `{{ driver_first_name }}` is referencing the `driver_first_name` that's being passed into the context.

Comment: Thank you! However, adding the value to the "driver_first_name" did not help my cause. All it did was add "driver_first_name" into the text area of the html template. However, when I reload the page it text gets reset to the default.

Comment: @ZarifAkhtab You're welcome, and hopefully I can help you resolve this issue.  For clarification, which template is the one containing your text fields and the like?  I noticed in your views that you have two possible templates that can be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure as i'm fairly new to Django myself, but from what i've done previously you can get the POST data from the request that is passed in, like this:

```
request.POST['driver_first_name']
```

which raises an error if no data is present or from

```
request.POST.get('driver_first_name', 'optionaldefaultvalue')
```

which returns None if no data is present in the specified field, or an optional default.

It might also be easier to do what you are after with django's inbuilt forms